# Understanding the strace output on a mac

Tags: macos, strace

I am seeing syscalls that I do not understand. Multiple calls ending with _nocancel. E.g. open_nocancel, close_nocancel. What are these calls and where do I find information about these? Google does not answer this question surprisingly and neither does the book on Mac Internals I have.

Btw. strace does not exist on a mac, I have to use dtruss instead.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: To me this doesn't seem too broad, but it's part of the hazards of using non-free software: you can't always get answers to this type of question.